# Is it possible to send audio through both the headphone out jack and line in jack on my MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio

Is it possible to send audio through both the headphone out jack and line in jack on my MacBook Pro? My reason for doing this is because I'm trying to monitor audio on headphones on a mixing program while sending audio out to loud speakers. I know it would be possible if I bought an external/USB sound device, but I'm out of the country for the next few months and finding a place that sells one will be difficult.

Comment: Did you look at the AudioMidi Setup app in your utility folder- Aggregate devices.